# Simulating many agents in PyTorch using multiprocessing

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, montecarlo

I want to simulate multiple reinforcement learning agents that are coded using Pytorch. The agents do not share any data dynamically, so I expect that the task should be "embarassingly parallel". I need a lot of simulations (I want to see what is the distribution my agents converge to) so I hope to speed it up using multiprocessing.

I have a `model` class that stores all the parameters of my agents (which are the same across agents) and the environment. I can simulate N agents over T periods using

```
model.simulate(N = 10, T = 50)
```

My class would then run simulation loops and store all networks and simulation histories. I am very new to parallel programming, and I (naively) try the following:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

num_processes = 6
processes = []
for _ in range(num_processes):
    p = mp.Process(target=model.simulate(N = 10, T = 50), args= ())
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

For now I do not even try to store results, I just want to see some speed-up. But the time it takes to run the code above is roughly the same as when I simply run a loop and do 6 simulations consequently:

```
for _ in range(num_processes):
    model.simulate(N = 10, T = 50)
```

I also tried to make processes for different instances of the `model` class, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in this line

```py
p = mp.Process(target=model.simulate(N = 10, T = 50), args= ())
```

The part `model.simulate(N = 10, T = 50)` is executed first, then the result (I'm assuming `None` if there is no return from this method) is passed to the `mp.Process` as the `target` parameter. So you are doing all the computation sequentially, and not performing it on the new processes.

What you need to do instead is to pass the `simulate` function (without executing it) and provide the args separately.

i.e. something like...

```py
p = mp.Process(target=model.simulate, args=(10, 50))
```

Providing `target=model.simulate` will pass a reference to the function itself rather than executing it and passing the result. This way it will be executed on the new process and you should acheive the parallelism.

See [offical docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html) for an example.